# Spring + iBatis + Hessian caching

Tags: spring, caching, ibatis, hessian

I have a Hessian service on Spring + iBatis working on Tomcat. 
I'm wondering how to cache results...

I've made the following config in my sqlmap file:

```
<sqlMap namespace="Account">

<cacheModel id="accountCache" type="MEMORY" readOnly="true" serialize="false">
    <flushInterval hours="24"/>
    <flushOnExecute statement="Account.addAccount"/>
    <flushOnExecute statement="Account.deleteAccount"/>
    <property name="reference-type" value="STRONG" />
</cacheModel>

<typeAlias alias="Account" type="domain.Account" />

    <select id="getAccounts" resultClass="Account" cacheModel="accountCache">
        fix all;
        select id, name, pin from accounts;
    </select>

    <select id="getAccount" parameterClass="Long" resultClass="Account" cacheModel="accountCache">
        fix all;
        select id, name, pin from accounts where id=#id#;
    </select>

    <insert id="addAccount" parameterClass="Account">
    fix all;
        insert into accounts (id, name, pin) values (#id#, #name#, #pin#);
    </insert>

    <delete id="deleteAccount" parameterClass="Long">
        fix all;
        delete from accounts where id = #id#;
    </delete>
</sqlMap>
```

Then i've done some tests... I have a hessian client application. I'm calling getAccounts several times and after each call it's a query to DBMS.

How to make my service to query DBMS only a first time (after server restart) getAccounts called and for the following calls to use a cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The solution was to add

```
<settings cacheModelsEnabled="true" />
```

to my sqlMapConfig file.